# $_POST with variable issue

Tags: php, post

Can anyone tell me if there is any error in the code. Because I think that $ _POST is not properly defined, because it didn't skips the first IF even when there is some value

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; $i++) {
    $hbs = "other_text".$i;

    if($_POST['other_text'.$i]]=="") { 
        echo "You didn't eneter quantity"; 
        die(); 
    }

    if(!is_int($_POST['other_text'.$i]) || isset($_POST['vin'.$i])) {
        $vins .= '<tr><td>'.$_POS['vin_lbl'.$i].'</td><td>'.$_POS['other_text'.$i].'</td></tr>';
    }
    else {
        echo "Incorrect data for quantity. \n Please go back.";
    }
}
```

Now show me that Undefined index: other_text1 so i checked the form in html and this is the code of the textbox `<input type="text" value="1" disabled name="other_text1" style="width:15px; padding:1px; height:10px; font-size:9px; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:none; ">`

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)` to see what the `$_POST` variable contains.

Comment: Are you posting a form to this page?  Have you tried to debug?  `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: `if($_POST['other_text'.$i]]` one `]` too many, for one thing.

Comment: Then you have `.$_POS['other_text'.$i]` which should be `.$_POST['other_text'.$i]`. Shall I go on?

Comment: ... `$_POS['vin_lbl'.$i]` => `$_POST['vin_lbl'.$i]`

Comment: Your code is literally **S-t-i-t-c-h-e-d** with bad syntax and errors. Say you didn't "write" that.

Comment: I realized that it could not initialize the text box on the form but I do not know why
[code]
<input type="text" value="1" disabled name="other_text1" style="width:15px; padding:1px; height:10px; font-size:9px; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:none; ">
[code]

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have an extra closing bracket here

```
if($_POST['other_text'.$i]] <----
```

and your missing a semi colon here

```
echo "You didn't eneter quantity"; die() <-----
```

this script SHOULD look like

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; $i++) {
    $hbs = "other_text".$i;
    if($_POST['other_text'.$i]=="")
    {
      echo "You didn't eneter quantity"; die(); 
    }
    if(!is_int($_POST['other_text'.$i])|| isset($_POST['vin'.$i]))
    {
      $vins .= '<tr><td>'.$_POST['vin_lbl'.$i].'</td><td>'.$_POST['other_text'.$i].'</td></tr>';
    }
    else echo"Incorrect data for quantity. \n Please go back.";
  }
```

Comment: Now show me that Undefined index: other_text1 so i checked the form in html and this is the code of the textbox
<input type="text" value="1" disabled name="other_text1" style="width:15px; padding:1px; height:10px; font-size:9px; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:none; ">

Comment: is it disabled for a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Why there is an additional closing square bracket `]]` ??

```
if($_POST['other_text'.$i]]==""){ echo "You didn't eneter quantity"; die() }
```

It should be

```
if($_POST['other_text'.$i]==""){ echo "You didn't eneter quantity"; die() }
```

You also have a spell mistake `$_POS` ?? it should be `$_POST`

```
$vins .= '<tr><td>'.$_POST['vin_lbl'.$i].'</td><td>'.$_POST['other_text'.$i].'</td></tr>';
```

Also remove `de here` after the loop

Comment: Now show me that Undefined index: other_text1 so i checked the form in html and this is the code of the textbox <input type="text" value="1" disabled name="other_text1" style="width:15px; padding:1px; height:10px; font-size:9px; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:none; ">

Comment: Remove the attribute `disable` from the field instead you can do in this way
`<input type="text" value="1" readonly="readonly" name="other_text1" style="width:15px; padding:1px; height:10px; font-size:9px; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:none; ">`